# OWASP ZAP Docker Full Scan Fails with Proxy Error

Tags: docker, proxy, owasp, zap

I am attempting to perform a full scan against my application using the OWASP ZAP docker packaged scan, however the scans are failing to connect to the proxy with `ProxyError`, and the error seems to be inconsistent. Sometimes it will be `NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f89c980ee80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')`, other times it will be `ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')`.

The command I am using is basic one from the [documentation](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/full-scan/):
`docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-full-scan.py -t https://my.webapp.com`

Running the baseline-scan works without issue, and running the full-scan against other [demo](https://demo.testfire.net/) sites works fine too.

As [suggested](https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/why-cant-zap-connect-to-my-website/) I have run `curl` against my application from inside the container and 200 is returned as expected, so I am unsure what needs to be configured to enable the connection.

Comment: Thats really weird, especially as the baseline scan works ok. The baseline scan and the full scan both do exactly the same things to start with, so I'm really surprised that one works and the other one doesnt!

Can you see when the connection errors are happenning?

Comment: With debug messages on I can see the Active Scan reaches 57% before getting stuck and failing. Is there anyway to see what test it is on when it fails?
Also, I am able to run an automated scan from the desktop application against the endpoint without issue.